# How to configure R enterprise to work with obiee12c

Tags: machine-learning, r

I have installed R enterprise in the obiee12c server. Now, I need to configure R enterprise to work   with the OBIEE12c. Where and how should I configure the R enterprise to work with the my BI server.

Answer (score 0):

R Enterprise configuration process to work with OBIEE12c are as follows:

1. Open your instance of Oracle BI Presentation Services and click Administration. In the Administration page, click Issue SQL. The Issue SQL dialog displays.
2. In the Issue SQL dialog, enter and issue the following stored procedures:

   call NQSRegisterScript("filerepo://obiee.Clustering.xml")
   call NQSRegisterScript("filerepo://obiee.RegressionCreateModel.xml")
   call NQSRegisterScript("filerepo://obiee.RegressionScoreModel.xml")
   call NQSRegisterScript("filerepo://obiee.Outliers.xml")
   call NQSRegisterScript("filerepo://obiee.Regression.xml")
   call NQSRegisterScript("filerepo://obiee.RegressionCorrelation.xml")
   call NQSRegisterScript("filerepo://obiee.TimeSeriesForecast.xml")
3. Locate and open NQSConfig.INI and in the ADVANCED_ANALYTICS_SCRIPT section make the following updates:

   In the CONNECTION_POOL property, specify the name of the connection pool to be defined in the repository.

   For example, suppose the database name is ORE and the connection pool name is ORECP. Then in the CONNECTION_POOL property, you would enter: ORE.ORECP

   If the ORE database and the source data are located in the same database, then you can improve the speed of the R execution by setting the CONNECTION_POOL property to the source database connection pool.

   In the TARGET property, set the value to "ORE". For example, TARGET="ORE".
4. Finally, Test the configuration by running an Oracle BI Server query.

Please visit the following document for the more details
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIESG/answersconfigset.htm#BIESG1311